# Как из telegram бота, отправлять сообщение discord ботом в канал дискорда?

Tags: python, telegram, бот, discord.py

как можно реализовать отправку сообщения из моего telegram бота в канал моего сервера через discord бота?

Comment: Принимаете сообщение из ТГ бота, сохраняете сообщение, отправляете сохранёное сообщение в дискорд бот... логично же?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого необходимо установить библиотеку **discord-webhook**:

> pip install discord-webhook

Далее импортируем в коде DiscordWebhook:

> from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook

Вставляем в нужную часть кода строку:

> DiscordWebhook(url="URL", content="MSG").execute()

**url**: ссылка на вебхук Discord канала. (**Канал » Интеграция » Вебхуки » Новый вебхук**)

**content**: текст сообщения полученный вашим тг ботом.

*Информация взята из* [*официальной документации.*](https://pypi.org/project/discord-webhook/)